# WebStorm: Why does using new Date result in this warning

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webstorm

**Background**

I am doing unit testing using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org) and the following line:

```
describe ('', function() {

    it ('', function () {

        var myDate = new Date ('1 january, 2016 07:31:00');
    };
};
```

results in this warning in WebStorm:

> Interface can not be instantiated.
>
> Checks code for warnings implied by Google Closure Compiler annotations. This includes correct usage of @abstract, @inteface and @implements tags.

I am not using any JSdoc tags in my code.

**Questions:**

1. Why do I get this warning?
2. Can I do something differently besides suppressing the warning to make it disappear?

Comment: do you have defined Date (i.e. `var Date = require('Date')`) somewhere in the file?

Comment: No I do not. Should I irrespective of that `new Date()` is Javascript built-in object?

Comment: which version of webstorm do you use?

Comment: 11.0.3 confirmed this happens

Comment: I use version 11.0.3, Build #WS-143.1559

Comment: I created a new project, made one file with your source, and actualy made the `closurecompiler` run over it. No error, nothing. I don't have any idea why this happens. Next to that - in the empty project with nothing except the closurecompiler, I dit not get the error. I did in a scratch file next to the actual file though.

Comment: It happens when using the framework Mocha to do unit testing. The code line is encapsulated in a `describe( it ());` statement. But I can't see why that should cause the warning ....

Comment: How can this issue be reproduced? Is the warning reported by WebStorm own inspection or some 3rd party plugin? Unfortunately, it is not reproduced for me when running this command: "java -jar /path/to/node_modules/google-closure-compiler/compiler.jar --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js mocha-test.js"